# What's the use case for Workbox NetworkOnly strategy

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to wrap my head around service workers and WorkBox.

Workbox provides a number of strategies to handle loading data in offline. Everything is crystal clear except the [NetworkOnly](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_only) strategy.
The question is simple.

Why do may need to use this NetworkOnly strategy in the first place?

If all it does is accessing the network and fail if we're offline, then I get the same effect with no router and no strategy at all. If I don't register a router for some URL and try to access it from an app I'll get exactly the same results, it will just fail.

Can somebody propose a more or less realistic use case when I might want to use this strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the least-used strategy, but there are a few scenarios where it comes in handy.

When using [`setDefaultHandler()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#set_a_default_handler) to specify a strategy (say, `StaleWhileRevalidate`) to use when there are no matching routes, you might want to explicitly create a route that matches some criteria and applies a `NetworkFirst` strategy:

```
import {NetworkOnly, StaleWhileRevalidate} from 'workbox-routing';
import {registerRoute, setDefaultHandler} from 'workbox-routing';

// Ensure that requests that include /api/ go against the network.
registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.pathname.includes('/api'),
  new NetworkOnly()
);

setDefaultHandler(new StaleWhileRevalidate());
```

Additionally, using `NetworkOnly` allows you to apply [Workbox plugins](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins) to respond to various lifecycle events, like `requestWillFetch`, `fetchDidFail`, and `fetchDidSucceed`.